# Is this washing machine drain hose too long/ installed wrong?

Tags: plumbing, drain, washing-machine

Yellow is the current setup

[image]

Should the hose be shortened/rerouted? I'm thinking it would have a hard time draining properly, and I believe my washing machine has issues rinsing. Could this be the cause?

I was thinking of changing it to closer match the original drain hose in the diagram.

Answer (score 2):

I would agree the extra loop will create increased resistance and possibly not pump as well.

I would shorten the hose if nothing else to reduce the back pressure on the pump.

I know my washer has a check valve at the exit of the pump so it should not let dirty water flow back but I would think eliminating any flow restrictions and a longer hose is a resistance to flow that if eliminated may solve your rinse issue.